# Record task manager history while on lock screen

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, task-manager, windows-server-2012-r2

It appears as though the history in the task manager doesn't get recorded while the computer is on the lock screen. I have a PC I'm using as a server and I would like to see the last 4 minutes of usage when I RDP, (you get 4 minutes when you set update speed to low).

If I intentionally cause some usage, like disk usage on file share, the history isn't recorded unless I'm currently RDP'd or logged in locally.

The system is server 2012 r2, but I've seen the same exact behavior in 8 and 8.1. If the system is displaying the lock screen, even though the user is signed in, no history is recorded.

How can I get it to keep recording history?

Answer (score 2):

What you are wanting then is Perfmon. Click Start and in the search box type in `perfmon`. Run that and you can add in your counters and the timespan and interval.

[image: Example Here]

Comment: +1, perfmon has been there since the beginning of Windows NT in 1993, very powerful tool, not used enough. It has access to all performance counters not just the limited set in task manager. You can also set it to record counters when no user is logged on and review them later.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf Exactly, I use the perf counters via WMI and PowerShell for performance monitoring on "trouble" computers and our various servers.